# Powershell Script does not wait for the response from Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet

Tags: rest, api, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am new to powershell. I have a powershell script which basically makes an REST API request and gets back a JSON response. But I have an issue with the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet. I mean the script sometimes doesn't wait for the response and continues with the next line of code.

Is there some trick in powershell which asks the code to wait for the API response and then run the remaining code. Below is my code

```
if ($EventID -eq '4726') { 
    $ad_user = "$TargetUsername@avayaaws.int" 

    $jsonbody = @{

                   "setupName" = "avayadev-or"
                   "instanceName" = "000_JumpServer_DMZ"
                   "command" = "$Command"
                    "parameters" = @{
                                     "mobile" = "$getMobileAttr"
                                     "ad_user"="$ad_user"
                                     "label" ="$environment"
                                    }
                   "eventToken" = "optional"

                  } | ConvertTo-Json

    #$response = Start-Job {
    #    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method $verb -Body $jsonbody -Headers $header 
    #} | wait-job | receive-job 
    #$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method $verb -Body $jsonbody -Headers $header
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method $verb -Body $jsonbody -Headers $header
    $EventTrigger = $translEvent4726
    Write-Output "Response is: $response"
    PushLogs -transaction $EventTrigger -adUser $ad_user -transResult $response

}
```

I have tried many ways like using Out-Null and Wait-Job, Recieve-Job but couldn't get it to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i don't think you need `| ConvertTo-Json` try it without the convertion. also: what is the content of `$response`?

Comment: also use `Invoke-RestMethod` with APIs. there is no `-Wait`-switch as it always returns the server responses. maybe the server has a flood protection? look into the responses.

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz the response is a JSON response as such below.

`{
status=Success,
message=Command submitted, 
eventToken=optional
}`

My issue is the script sometimes doesn't wait for the response.

Comment: I meant the response from the failing ones.

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz I have tried Invoke-RestMethod but no luck. The response is null because it doesn't wait for the result and hence prints nothing in the response.

Comment: Try setting the TimeoutSec paramter :  Invoke-WebRequest $Uri -TimeoutSec 9999

Comment: According to official documentation, default is 0, which is indefinite. However, I saw notice on some blogs that this wouldn't be true and the default timeout might be 100 seconds so it is worth a try. Unfortunately, I have no api call I can test that would take such a lengthy time.

Comment: Any solution/workaround did you found it?